# Reuse last entered attribute values

Tags: qgis

I'm not sure of the correct terminology, so I'll describe what I'm looking for.

I've used it before, but can't remember where, but what is the tool/plugin to use when adding features to say a point feature and it retains the attribute data from the last point added, so that the new attribute data is pretty much already populated?

I am using QGIS 3.0.3.

Comment: Try menu Settings -> Options -> Digitizing -> "Reuse last entered attribute values" must be activate

Answer (score -1):

From QGIS 3.2.x:
[image: Adding field to table, interactive way]

One can fill the new field with a value by using the field calculator or the advanced field calculator(Vector table -> advanced python calculator)

[image: Value is an expression which copies the data from a already entered row]

As far as I can see the routines look the same from version 2.18 onwards.

Comment: The question appears to be about using the values from a previously created feature on a newly created feature, not calculating a field on all features.